# PHP - mkdir default user is www-data, how to change?

Tags: php

I have a script PHP that to create a folder and some files in this folder. Ok, I can done easily with `mkdir` in PHP but the folder is owned by `www-data` it’s weird user or group that I didn't log in. Because that so I can’t modify this folder and files in this folder (delete).

Could someone suggest me how to fix this? Can I create the folder by our current log in user? It’s a public folder for every users (should `chmod 775`). And this is created folders by PHP script and can have many folder so I dont't want to run sudo chmod all of theses folders every time a new folder is created!

Comment: Try [`chown`](http://php.net/chown)?

Comment: That's the Apache user. Set your server up with `suexec`/`suphp` or `php-fpm`.

Comment: You can't directly. You cannot "chown away" directories/files to another account, UNLESS you're running as root. You also do NOT want your webserver running as root. as mario said, you need suexec or some external suid app you can call to do the chown on your behalf.

Comment: Maybe, you're looking for http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html module.

Answer (score 4):

Any folder created by any application running under the http server service will be owned by the user executing such application (or component of the application). That being said, if you're running an Apache HTTP daemon which the child processes owner is the www-data user, any folder created by any php script will be owned by such user.

You'll not be able to chown() any FS entry to other user, since www-data doesn't have permissions to do so. You can change it manually via command line with super user permissions (uid == 0) using the `chown` command line binary.